# Self signed proxy client

Tags: http, go, proxy, self-signed

I need to create a function that returns a self signed proxy http.Client and I couldn't find any working solution.

I am attaching my current code that doesn't seem to be working.

```
func CreateProxyClient(server string,serverProxy string, sid string, portProxy int) (*Client, error) {
    http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}

    proxyURL, _ := url.Parse("http://" + serverProxy+":"+strconv.Itoa(portProxy) )
    http.DefaultTransport = &http.Transport{
        Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyURL),
    }

    var netClient = &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second * 1,
    }

    resp, _ := http.Get("http://"+server+":443")
    fmt.Printf("%d",resp.StatusCode)
    return &Client{netClient, server, sid, "", ""}, nil
}
```

I

Answer (score 0):

add this to http.Transport:

```
TLSNextProto: make(map[string]func(authority string, c *tls.Conn) http.RoundTripper),
```

Comment: it is not working... I am getting the same error message: "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"